# Applying substitutions on formulae in logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Do the following substitutions. If undefined, explain why.

- $ (p \land \top \equiv r)[\bot := r] $
- $((\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(g(x,y) = z))[z := f(x) = y ]$
- $(p \rightarrow q \land \bot)[p := \top] $

My answers :

- $(p \land \top \equiv r)$
- $((\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(g(x,y) = f(x) = y)$
- $(\top \rightarrow q \land \bot)$

I want to make sure my answers is correct.

Comment: I am not sure about the second one: the question looks not wellformed:  z is a variable, while $ f(x) = y $ is a predicate and you should not replace one by another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first proposed substitution is not permitted : $\bot$ is a constant (called *falsum*: it is always *false*); so you cannot replace it with a sentential letter (which may have as value *true* or *false*)

The substitution :

> $((∀x)(∀y)(∀z)(g(x,y)=z))[z:=f(x)=y]$

is not *allowed* , first because $f(x)=y$ is a *formula* and you must use *terms* when substitute *individual variables*.

In any case, also if we use in place of the (pseudo-)term $f(x)=y$ the term $f(x)$ or the term $y$, they are **not** substitutable for $z$ in the above formula, because if we perform the subst, the variables $x$ in $f(x)$ or $y$ will be "captured" by the quantifiers in front of the formula.

The third one is fine.

Comment: It is not an formula it is even worse it is a predicate

Comment: @Willemien - why not a formula ? in first-order PA, we have a *function* symbol, i.e $S(x)$ (the *successor* function). Thus $S(x)=y$ is perfectly well-formed as formula; of course, it is **not** a *term* (where $S(x)$ is).

Comment: Also you can't perform the subst because $z$ is captured by $ (\forall z)$. So you can't take it out. Right ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  a function is something that transforms one term into another term, while a predicate transformes a term  into a truthvalue  so P(x) and P(s(x)) are wellformed (where s is the successer function) but P(x = y) is not wellformed.

Comment: @Tennisman - but the substitution specified by $(g(x,y)=z))[z:=f(x)=y]$ says that you have to put in place of $z$ inside the formula $(g(x,y)=z))$ the (not well-formed) "term" $f(x)=y$. $z$ is  not "captured"; it is already there, and it is a bounded variable, because it is in the scope of $(\forall z)$ ... and this is Ok. Is the subst that is not permitted.

Comment: Yeah I mean the z is bounded to $ (\forall z)$ so i can't take it out in the first place. Do i write undefined or write the original one ? Because when you can't substitute and the variable you want to take out is bounded, we write the original one and not "undefined". Here you say it's undefined as we can't put in a formula.

Comment: @Tennisman - according to Tourlakis, page 133, the sub $A[x:=t]$ is *undefined* if $A$ is $(\forall y)B$, where $y$ *does* occur in $t$. In our case : $A$ is $(∀x)(∀y)(∀z)(g(x,y)=z))$ with and $t$ is $f(x)=y$; thus, $x$ and $y$ occur in $t$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So $ f(x) = y $ is a formula and $ x = y $ is a term ?

Comment: @Tennisman - No, both are formulae; $x, y$ and $f(x)$ are *terms*. The *equality* symbol ($=$) is a *predicate* symbol: it works like $P(x,y)$. Formally we have $=(x,y)$ that is written (for readibility) as $x=y$.